# Morphia trying to map classes, which are actually string values

Tags: java, mongodb, exception

I am currently working with Morphia to create a logger analysis web Gui. I have one entity name "Entry" which contains some specific values on log entries - mostly string values. In one of these values called LoggerName the package and the class is written, e.g. "myPackage.MyClass" as a string.

For some reason Morphia analysis this "LoggerName" and tries to generate a Morphia object out of it, even thow it is just a string value, throwing an exception like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myPackage.MyClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getClass(DefaultCreator.java:175)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:87)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:102)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:64)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:793)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:250)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:191)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:150)
    at services.DataService.getAllEntries(DataService.java:25)
    at controllers.ApplicationController.index(ApplicationController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.RequestHandler.invokeController(RequestHandler.java:125)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.RequestHandler.getResponse(RequestHandler.java:105)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.RequestHandler.handleRequest(RequestHandler.java:46)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.FormHandler.nextHandler(FormHandler.java:85)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.FormHandler.handleRequest(FormHandler.java:34)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.InboundCookiesHandler.nextHandler(InboundCookiesHandler.java:120)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.InboundCookiesHandler.handleRequest(InboundCookiesHandler.java:41)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.LocaleHandler.nextHandler(LocaleHandler.java:57)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.LocaleHandler.handleRequest(LocaleHandler.java:46)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.DispatcherHandler.nextHandler(DispatcherHandler.java:152)
    at io.mangoo.routing.handlers.DispatcherHandler.handleRequest(DispatcherHandler.java:124)
    at io.undertow.server.RoutingHandler.handleRequest(RoutingHandler.java:93)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.ExceptionHandler.handleRequest(ExceptionHandler.java:29)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:243)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:134)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:58)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:559)
```

Of course, the class does not exist.

Here is the Entry class:

```
@Entity(value = "entries", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Entry extends MorphiaModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3787666518698664992L;
    private String level;
    private String loggerName;
    private String message;
    private String threadName;
    private Integer millis;
    private String date;

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getLoggerName() {
        return loggerName;
    }

    public void setLoggerName(String loggerName) {
        this.loggerName = loggerName;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getThreadName() {
        return threadName;
    }

    public void setThreadName(String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    public Integer getMillis() {
        return millis;
    }

    public void setMillis(Integer millis) {
        this.millis = millis;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```